# How to extract two values from dict in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, dictionary

I'm using python3 and and i have data set. That contains the following data. I'm trying to get the desire value from this data list. I have tried many ways but unable to figure out how to do that.

```
slots_data = [
        {
            "id":551,
            "user_id":1,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
        {
            "id":552,
            "user_id":1,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
        {
            "id":525,
            "user_id":3,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
        {
            "id":524,
            "user_id":3,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
        {
            "id":553,
            "user_id":1,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
         {
            "id":550,
            "user_id":2,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        }
    ]
    
    
    # Desired output 
    # [
    # {"user_id":1,"slots_ids":[551,552,553]}
    # {"user_id":2,"slots_ids":[550]}
    # {"user_id":3,"slots_ids":[524,525]}
    # ]
```

I have tried in the following way and obviously this is not correct. I couldn't figure out the solution of this problem :

```
final_list = []
for item in slots_data:
    obj = obj.dict()
    obj = {
    "user_id":item["user_id"],
    "slot_ids":item["id"]
    }

    final_list.append(obj)

print(set(final_list))
```

Comment: I hope it helps
https://www.pythonprogramming.in/how-to-group-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-in-python.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of good answers here.

If I was doing this, I would base my answer on `setdefault` and/or `collections.defaultdict` that can be used in a similar way. I think the `defaultdict` version is very readable but if you are not already importing collections you can do without it.

Given your data:

```
slots_data = [
    {
        "id":551,
        "user_id":1,
        "time":"199322002",
        "expire":"199322002"
    },
    {
        "id":552,
        "user_id":1,
        "time":"199322002",
        "expire":"199322002"
    },
    #....
]
```

You can reshape it into your desired output via:

```py
## -------------------
## get the value for the key user_id if it exists
## if it does not, set the value for that key to a default
## use the value to append the current id to the sub-list
## -------------------
reshaped = {}
for slot in slots_data:
    user_id = slot["user_id"]
    id = slot["id"]
    reshaped.setdefault(user_id, []).append(id)
## -------------------
 
## -------------------
## take a second pass to finish the shaping in a sorted manner
## -------------------
reshaped = [
    {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "slots_ids": sorted(reshaped[user_id])
    }
    for user_id
    in sorted(reshaped)
]
## -------------------

print(reshaped)
```

That will give you:

```
[
   {'user_id': 1, 'slots_ids': [551, 552, 553]},
   {'user_id': 2, 'slots_ids': [550]},
   {'user_id': 3, 'slots_ids': [524, 525]}
]
```

Comment: Brother sorting is required on `slots_ids` and `users_ids` list. as you can see in the question where i mentioned the desired output

Comment: Sure thing... updated with sorting on both lists if needs be.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer added here has a nice solution, but here's one without using `pandas`:

```
users = {}
for item in slots_data:
    # Check if we've seen this user before,
    if item['user_id'] not in users:
        # if not, create a new entry for them
        users[item['user_id']] = {'user_id': item['user_id'], 'slot_ids': []}

    # Add their slot ID to their dictionary
    users[item['user_id']]['slot_ids'].append(item['id'])

# We only need the values (dicts)
output_list = list(users.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say try using `pandas` to group the user id's together and convert it back to a dictionary

```
pd.DataFrame(slots_data).groupby('user_id')['id'].agg(list).reset_index().to_dict('records')

[{'user_id': 1, 'id': [551, 552, 553]},
 {'user_id': 2, 'id': [550]},
 {'user_id': 3, 'id': [525, 524]}]
```

Comment: panda is a big library for this job. It will increase the size of docker container.

Answer (score 1):

thriough just simple loop way

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for i in slots_data:
...     if i['user_id'] not in result:
...             result[i['user_id']] = []
...     result[i['user_id']].append(i['id'])
... 
>>> output = []
>>> for i in result:
...     dict_obj = dict(user_id=i, slots_id=result[i])
...     output.append(dict_obj)
... 
>>> output
[{'user_id': 1, 'slots_id': [551, 552, 553]}, {'user_id': 3, 'slots_id': [525, 524]}, {'user_id': 2, 'slots_id': [550]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be made in a using listcomprehension:

```py
final_list = [{"user_id": user_id, "id":sorted([slot["id"] for slot in slots_data if slot["user_id"] == user_id])} for user_id in sorted(set([slot["user_id"] for slot in slots_data]))]
```

A more verbose and better formatted version of the same code:

```py
all_user_ids = [slot["user_id"] for slot in slots_data]
unique_user_ids = sorted(set(all_user_ids))
final_list = [
    {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "id": sorted([slot["id"] for slot in slots_data if slot["user_id"] == user_id])
    }
    for user_id in unique_user_ids]
```

Explanation:

1. get all the user ids with list comprehension
2. get the unique user ids by creating a set
3. create the final list of dictionaries using list comprehension.
4. each field `id` is of itself a list with list comprehension. We get the id of the slot, and only add it to the list, if the user ids match

Comment: You can do a lot of stuff in python with one-liners! That doesn't make this good practise. Unreadable.

Comment: @nigel239 You are right. is it better this way?

Comment: i have applied you code but the sorting is missing and sorting is required on `slots_ids` and `users_ids` list. as you can see in the question where i mentioned the desired output

Comment: @AhmedYasin please mention special requirements like sorting in the question itself, when asking next time. otherwise it is very difficult to deduce, whether it happened by chance that your data was sorted, or whether it was a requirement. Anyway: see my updated answer

Comment: @JeanotZubler Generally, it's considered better practice not to use one-liners when nesting `for`-loops (Or doing any kind of more complex logic). this keeps up readability, and thus also maintainability. But, this is better. Yes. (See https://hashnode.com/post/when-should-you-not-use-list-comprehensions-in-python-cj2a35qsh0020u9532z9e1n6z for example)

Comment: @JeanotZubler Yeah sure. I'll be careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get it done. Purely Python. Without any dependencies.

```py
slots_data = [
        {
            "id":551,
            "user_id":1,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
        {
            "id":552,
            "user_id":1,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
        {
            "id":525,
            "user_id":3,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
        {
            "id":524,
            "user_id":3,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
        {
            "id":553,
            "user_id":1,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        },
         {
            "id":550,
            "user_id":2,
            "time":"199322002",
            "expire":"199322002"
        }
    ]

user_wise_slots = {}
for slot_detail in slots_data:
    if not slot_detail["user_id"] in user_wise_slots:
        user_wise_slots[slot_detail["user_id"]] = {
            "user_id": slot_detail["user_id"],
            "slot_ids": []
        }
    user_wise_slots[slot_detail["user_id"]]["slot_ids"].append(slot_detail["id"])
print(user_wise_slots.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas you can easily achieve the result.
First install pandas  if you don't have as follow

> pip install pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(slots_data) #create dataframe
df1 = df.groupby("user_id")['id'].apply(list).reset_index(name="slots_ids") #groupby on user_id and combine elements of id in list and give the column name is slots_ids
final_slots_data = df1.to_dict('records') # convert dataframe into a list of dictionary
final_slots_data
```

Output:

```
[{'user_id': 1, 'slots_ids': [551, 552, 553]},
 {'user_id': 2, 'slots_ids': [550]},
 {'user_id': 3, 'slots_ids': [525, 524]}]
```